# Commas disappear from Python 3 sys.argv in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have a script in Python 3.7 which runs based on arguments passed to it in `sys.argv`. These arguments are video titles and so almost always include spaces: as a result I use commas as a deliminator and `split(',')` to separate them out.

This works fine in bash, but when I sent the script to a coworker it fails to split the string where he put the commas. I wrote another simple script for testing purposes:

```
import sys

print('Number of arguments: '+str(len(sys.argv)))

for arg in sys.argv:
  print(arg)

console_input = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]).strip()
print('Combined: '+console_input)
print('Divided: ')
for divided_arg in console_input.split(','):
  print('- '+divided_arg.strip())
```

On my computer, when I type `python3 test.py Foo Bar, Baz` this returns the following:

```
Number of arguments: 4
/Users/michael/test.py
Foo
Bar,
Baz
Combined: Foo Bar, Baz
Divided:
- Foo Bar
- Baz
```

On HIS (Windows 10) computer, it returns this instead:

```
Number of arguments: 4
C:\Users\john\Downloads\test.py
Foo
Bar
Baz
Combined: Foo Bar Baz
Divided:
- Foo Bar Baz
```

So it appears to me that Windows is stripping the commas from the arguments before passing them to Python, unless there's a problem in the way I'm handling `sys.argv` that I'm not seeing. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

I should note that when he installed Python, he had to add the executable to the `$PATH` variable manually in the registry editor. I'm not sure whether that could be the cause of this behavior.

Comment: Have you tried putting the arguments in quotes when running?

Comment: I'll ask him to do that and report back with the result. I'd prefer it if it wasn't necessary to surround the arguments with quotes—the script is designed to automate a boring and time-consuming task and so will be used by people who aren't familiar with the command line, so I'd like it to be as foolproof as possible—but if that's what necessary I can work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using CMD on Windows. If so, the parameters delimiters are spaces, but also some others like Comma(,) or Semicolon(;). You can find some details [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html). This means that they'll never be a part of the argument so you won't be able to do `console_input.split(',')`

For your case, I would suggest to do as Nick says and quote the arguments. However, if this will be used by people who aren't familiar with the command line, have you considered using as argument a csv file containing the Video titles?

Comment: The particular subset of titles that need to be updated will change every time, so I think that a CSV file might just add another layer of complexity and potentially confuse people, unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean; I'll probably just add something that prompts the user for a list of titles if they run the program without arguments. That way they can choose for themselves whether it's easier to put quotes around the list or type it in once they've started the script. Thanks for explaining why it wasn't working!

Comment: You linked to a page that's about the CMD shell and associated utilities. There would actually be no problem in that case. CMD doesn't remove the comma from the command-line that gets passed to Python. I can only reproduce the problem in PowerShell, which has become the default shell in Windows 10. There it can be escaped with a backtick (e.g. `python test.py Foo Bar\`, Baz`) or quotes (e.g. `python test.py Foo "Bar," Baz`).